# Importing modules from jupyter notebook to another jupyter notebook shared on gist

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I am using [docker-stacks](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/minimal-notebook) to run jupyter notebook.My notebook is shared on gist I want to import modules from another notebook shared on gist too.
What is the the best way to do it?